# Spring GraphQL ignore auth for introspection query

Tags: graphql-java, spring-graphql

I have a WebFilter that does some auth logic, write some context before calling chain.filter(exchange).

I'm using Spring GraphQL with GraphiQL enabled. I would like to skip auth for GraphiQL. As GraphiQL makes an introspection query to display the schema documentation. What is the correct way to ignore running the auth logic for introspection query ?

```
public class AuthFilter implements WebFilter {

    @Override
    public Mono<Void> filter(ServerWebExchange exchange, WebFilterChain chain) {
        ... do some auth logic here
        return chain.filter(exchange);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

From a web perspective, there is no way to only allow introspection queries - only the GraphQL engine can parse and schedule which operations are requested by the client.

Any attempt to manually parse or detect such queries could create a security problem if the web filter doesn't exactly replicate the same parsing behavior as graphql-java. Instead, in this case, I would [suggest securing operations and fields fetching at the API level](https://docs.spring.io/spring-graphql/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/#security) instead and allow generic public usage of the graphql web endpoint.